# java example in swt

Tags: java, swt

i just started learning swt and i'm trying to do an example i saw at the course and it does'nt work - it supposed to create a circle around the tip of the mouse and move with him 
but the circle is not at the right place - he moves with the mouse but not at the tip of it

here is the code :

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseMoveListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class CanvasKeyEvent {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(370, 380);
    final Canvas c=new Canvas(shell,SWT.NONE);
    c.setSize(370,380);
    c.setLocation(21, 21);
    c.addPaintListener(new Example());

    c.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener(){
         public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
          c.redraw();
         }    
        });

    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();            
    }

    display.dispose();

  }
  static class Example implements PaintListener {

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        int x  = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        e.gc.drawOval(x , y , 20 , 20);

    }

  }
}
```

someone know why it does'nt work well?

thank you

Comment: the thank you is for futere answering 
i didnt get an answer yet
sorry dor the confusion ..

Comment: You need to tell us what goes wrong when you run it.

Comment: the circle is not at the right place - he moves with the mouse but not at the tip of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better not to use `java.awt.MouseInfo` with SWT - `Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation()` is preferred.

The main issue with what you have is finding the mouse location relative to the Canvas. Try something like this:

```
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

    Canvas c = ((Canvas) e.getSource());

    Point pos = c.toDisplay(c.getLocation());

    Point relativePos = new Point(e.x - pos.x, e.y - pos.y);

    int x = Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().x + relativePos.x + 10;
    int y = Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().y + relativePos.y + 10;

    e.gc.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);
}
```